# Skipping a line While Parsing a File in Python ? Any simple/basic way?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-parsing

I am trying to parse a file line after line and edit the same/store it in an array and later dump it back to the file with the edited content.

But while parsing the file if I come across a particular line I wanted to skip the next line [or multiple lines] and then move forward with the parsing.

Below is the example code which I tried. And as soon I come across the line '// CODES' I tried to look for the next line and then skip them.

Instead is there any better way to skip a line while parsing a file and coming across a particular string?

```
    cc_array = []
    cc_input_file = open("<File Directory, File Name>"%(path,name),"r+")

    for lines in cc_input_file:
       cc_array.append(lines)

       if (f_1 == 0) and lines.startswith(" // CODES"):
           f_1 = 1
       if (f_1 == 1) and lines.startswith(" //-"):
           f_1 = 0
```

Please provide your comments or any better way to do the same.

UPDATE IN QUESTION:

Sorry for the confusion, when I say skip the next line - I need to add the next line as well into the array but I didnt wanted to add like an if statement to search for that particular line.

Say I come across " // CODES" , I add this line into the array and also next line into the array.

Then I add/append some content next to that line after " //-" which comes after " // CODES".

Something like shown below. Like as soon I hit the line " // CODES" I know the next line is " //---", so I just wanted to add that line into the array but I didnt wanted to search for that line and then add. Like blindly add one line [or may be multiple lines] after the searched line and the continue to the next.

[image]

WILL THIS WORK ?

```
cc_array = []
cc_input_file = open("<File Directory, File Name>"%(path,name),"r+")

for lines in cc_input_file:
   cc_array.append(lines)

   if (lines.startswith(" // CODES"):
       continue
```

Since the line next to " // CODES" is already appended and when I continue meaning it skips the next line right ? Is there any option to continue / skip multiple next lines after you reach a particular codes ?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the loop [`continue` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)?

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct, you can use following approach to skip appending contents to your list which starts with `//-` and load the rest.

```
 cc_array = []
    cc_input_file = open("<File Directory, File Name>"%(path,name),"r+")

    for lines in cc_input_file:
           if re.match("//-",lines):
              pass
           else:
              cc_array.append(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `continue` statement to get next value as I edited below.

**Code:**

```py
cc_array = []
cc_input_file = open("<File Directory, File Name>"%(path,name),"r+")

for lines in cc_input_file:
    if lines.startswith(" // CODES"):
        continue
    else:
        cc_array.append(lines)
```

Here you can find more information under 4.4 about [Python continue statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html)